# How to send a POST request for the Custom Location Extension

Tags: here-api

I am trying out the **HERE Maps REST API's - [Custom Location Extension](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/custom-location/topics/overview.html)** and run into a problem. It was mentioned that a `POST` request using the Corridor Search Using Coordinates for Custom Locationscan be used instead of a `GET` request if I want to submit a request with a large coordinate set, but the example `POST` request was not in the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/custom-location/topics/example-search-corridor.html).

I tried to figure out how to submit a `POST` request and this was how far I got:

**Request:**

```
POST /v1/search/corridor HTTP/1.1
Host: customlocation.cit.api.here.com

?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&route=52.51978,13.388211,
52.5198326,13.3882084,
52.5198402,13.3883495,
52.5147705,13.3891602,
52.514758,13.389155
&radius=100
&layerId=30
```

Response:

```
{
  "message": "Required parameters have not been provided",
  "status": "400 Bad Request",
  "error": "Required String parameter 'route' is not present",
  "targetLayerId": null
}
```

**Notes:**

- I wrote it here using the HTTP format
- This request was the same `GET` request in the documentation and I just tried to convert it as a `POST` request by moving the query parameter into the body and sending the request using `POST`.
- Body datatype is set as RAW TEXT

**Edit:**
(Further trial)

I also tried to move all the query params from the body to the url except `route`.

```
POST /v1/search/corridor ?app_id=Qk8YkRrHMbbbpkVipwIZ
&app_code=tYSXrAAHGEOcUB_cxbPQSA&radius=100&layerId=852 HTTP/1.1

route=52.51978,13.388211, 52.5198326,13.3882084, 
52.5198402,13.3883495, 
52.5147705,13.3891602, 
52.514758,13.389155
```

Response:
    {
      "message": "Required parameters have not been provided",
      "status": "400 Bad Request",
      "error": "Required String parameter 'route' is not present",
      "targetLayerId": null
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked at this a bit and was able to get a response via `POST`ing by removing the `route` from the querystring and sending it as a form key/value pair.  I used the demo credentials, and am testing using the Chrome plugin "Postman".  My POST URL looks like this:

`https://customlocation.cit.api.here.com/v1/search/corridor?layerId=30&radius=100&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg`

and then I set either a `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` key of "route" and then the value was a string of coordinates.  And then it came back with a successful response.  I did get the same error you mentioned when trying to put any payload as raw text.

Things I don't know: is there some limit on the form data values?

Good luck.  I do agree that the official document is pretty light on the `POST` examples, especially since they explicitly suggest that as a method for sending large payloads.